# Apache Ignite converting UInt16 to Int16

Tags: c#, ignite

I'm using Ignite to pass data between some processes and have run into a snag.  I have one class that needs to hold a value that could be a few different data types that I don't really want to create separate objects, caches and other resources for.  So for this I declare that property as of type 'object'.  One of the types of value potentially stores in that is UInt16.  However when I get the object back on the other side it thinks the type is Int16 which obviously causes some issues.

I created the below example program which shows the problem.  I tested for the type just via Immediate window testPerson.TestValue.GetType().  On server app that returns proper UInt16, on client it returns Int16. Any help much appreciated!

[image]

Person.cs

```
using System;

namespace Common
{
    [Serializable]
    public class Person
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public object TestValue { get; set; }
    }
}
```

ClientApp Program.cs

```
using Apache.Ignite.Core;
using Apache.Ignite.Core.Cache;
using Common;
using System;

namespace ClientApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var config = new IgniteConfiguration
            {
                IgniteInstanceName = "IgniteTest",
                BinaryConfiguration = new Apache.Ignite.Core.Binary.BinaryConfiguration(typeof(Person)),
                ClientMode = true
            };

            IIgnite ignite = Ignition.Start(config);

            ICache<int, Person> peopleCache = ignite.GetOrCreateCache<int, Person>("People");

            Person testPerson = peopleCache.Get(1);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

ServerApp Program.cs

```
using Apache.Ignite.Core;
using Apache.Ignite.Core.Cache;
using Common;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var config = new IgniteConfiguration
            {
                IgniteInstanceName = "IgniteTest",
                BinaryConfiguration = new Apache.Ignite.Core.Binary.BinaryConfiguration(typeof(Person)),
                ClientMode = false
            };

            IIgnite ignite = Ignition.Start(config);

            UInt16 testValue = 1005;

            var person1 = new Person()
            {
                Id = 1,
                Name = "Bill Cobble",
                TestValue = testValue
            };

            ignite.DestroyCache("People");
            ICache<int, Person> peopleCache = ignite.CreateCache<int, Person>("People");

            IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            Stream stream = new MemoryStream();
            formatter.Serialize(stream, person1);

            stream.Position = 0;
            Person result = formatter.Deserialize(stream) as Person;

            peopleCache.Put(person1.Id, person1);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ignite binary protocol only has `int16`, `int32`, `int64`, but no `uints` (because it was originally developed in Java with its poor type system).

So `UInt16` is written as `Int16` and so on.

Ignite.NET tries its best to handle this issue. If the `TestValue` property was of `UInt16` type, it would be deserialized correctly.

But with `object` type there is no way for Ignite.NET to know the original type.

---

**Workarounds:**

- Implement `IBinarizable` or `IBinarySerializer`, write an additional field indicating the object type, do the cast manually
- Implement `ISerializable`, in this case Ignite will preserve proper type automatically (version 2.0+)
- Use `BinaryFormatter` and store byte[] in Ignite cache (if you don't care for SQL and `IBinary`)